# Is it still an n by n matrix if it's filled with all zeroes?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say, for example I have a 5 x 5 matrix, but every row and every column is filled with a zero. Is it still a 5x5 matrix or is it a 1 x 1 matrix with a zero?

Comment: I would just call it a zero matrix with dimensions as needed to suit your needs.

Comment: It is still a $5$ by $5$ matrix.  You can think of it as a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^5$ to itself.

Comment: Yes, why would the values of the entries change the size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is still a $5 \times 5$ matrix. A matrix is essentially made up of three things:

1) A height (number of rows) $n$

2) A width (number of columns) $m$

3) A collection of entries (from some field) to fill up the $n \times m$ spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it doesn't matter if it is filled with zeros or not, if it has five rows and five columns all zero it is still a $5\times 5$ matrix

Answer (score 1):

If I write
$$
0 =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
it means that the zero matrix, here simply written as $0$. is the $5\times 5$ matrix with all elements being zero $0 \in \mathbb{F}$. So it is clear one works in $\mathbb{F}^{5\times 5}$ for some field $\mathbb{F}$.